# DynamoDB - Do I need lots of read capacities to handle multiple getItem-calls per page?

Tags: database, performance, scalability, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using DynamoDB to store items that are necessary to deliver a specific webpage. However, for one page load, the web server may easily need hundreds of items from about 2-5 different tables. If I have only one read capacity I can only make 2 eventually consistent DB calls per second. Of course if I need to get these items to deliver a webpage, I cannot wait one second for every DB call.

I already use batchGetItems to reduce the workload. Do I now need just lots of more read capacities or am I getting something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should be thinking caching, not fetching.

Either [AWS ElasticSearch](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/) (memcached) or [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/)-like caching.

You can also implement an in-process caching using [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained)

Comment: That would surely work for a "semi-static" webpage, but I'm developing a web app and the items are unique to every user. So even if I'd cache them for every user, it would still be way too much loading time at the initial fetch.

Comment: Then in that case either raise the read throughput until the speed is satisfying or save an 'initial state' somewhere else for easy fetching

Comment: So I need as much read capacities as I could have items in peak usage?  Sometimes it's 10, sometimes it's 1000 - yet I need always need to have 1000 read capacities running to answer peak usage requests? This does not sound like an efficient scalable solution...

Comment: I agree - Either 1) re-model your data 2) consider other NoSQL solutions 3) Cache

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to tune your read capacity based on usage and that's one of the advantages of using a hosted solution like DynamoDB. You can setup CloudWatch alarms, receive notifications through a SNS topic and create a simple app to increase/decrease your capacity. There is a nice post about it at: http://engineeringblog.txtweb.com/2013/09/txtweb-scaling-with-dynamodb/